# What are automation tools used for datawarehouse testing

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse, parallel-data-warehouse

In my recent interviews i have come across a common question, did you do automation on your datawarehouse test scripts?
I googled about this but didn't get any specific tool name(s) which are used for automating DWH tests.My test scripts are SQL queries which checks for counts, sum(), and unable to understand how the automation is possible on sql scripts.

Has anyone in the group has done automation, if yes then which tools are used to do so?

Your Help much appreciated.

Regards,
Geeme

Answer (score 0):

Fitnesse - Dbfit is one of best free tool available in market.